# Getting error with python oop with super

Tags: python, oop

I am trying this

```
In [1]: class Parent:
   ...:     def __init__(self):
   ...:         self.a =10
   ...:         self.b =20
   ...:


In [3]: class NewParent(Parent):
    def __init__self():
        super(NewParent,self).__init__()
        self.c =30
   ...:
```

When i do this

```
In [4]: c = NewParent()

In [5]: c
Out[5]: <__main__.NewParent instance at 0x2c98878>

In [6]: c.a
Out[6]: 10

In [7]: c.b
Out[7]: 20

In [8]: c.c
```

---

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
----> 1 c.c

AttributeError: NewParent instance has no attribute 'c'

Comment: Is the `init` method the same as `def __init__self():` in your code? Or it's the typo here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You goofed the method declaration on `NewParent`.

```
def __init__(self):
```

Comment: Now i get this `TypeError: must be type, not classobj` on super line

Comment: @user9: That's because you didn't make `Parent` a new-style class. Make it derive from `object`.

Answer (score 0):

```
class NewParent(Parent):
    def __init__self():
        super(NewParent,self).__init__()
        self.c =30
```

should be

```
class NewParent(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        #Your code here
```

Comment: Now i get this `TypeError: must be type, not classobj on super line`